# Is there a maximum size for sitemap files?

Tags: dynamic, sitemap

I was wondering: Is there a maximum size for sitemap files?
I'm trying to build a shopping site and I don't know if it's going to support constant size increasing dynamicaly. I don't even know if it is the correct way to put the products to be find by the search engines.

Comment: A detail well-explained answer for a similar question can be found here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887358/limitation-for-google-sitemap-xml-file-size/34972582#answer-34972582

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The limits are:

1. maximum 50000 urls
2. max 10MB file size (after un-gzipping).

Both limis apply.

Taken from [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=64d5ee9d37a083ad&hl=en)

Comment: Max file size was increased to 50MB since this answer was posted https://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_sitemap_size

Comment: It still looks like the numbers in the answer are correct per https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&topic=8476&ctx=topic

Comment: On that support site for google above it's been changed to 50MB as of this comment.

Comment: @user387049 Hi, I don't think so, but I would like to confirm. Does `<xhtml:link href="alternateURL" rel="alternate" hreflang="en"/>` count as a URL ? I have 15000 `<url>'s` and each one has 4 `<xhtml:link ../>` inside because of alternate langs. Can i use a single Sitemap? Thanks

Comment: Google now also has increased the size limit to 50 MB: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap

Answer (score 16):

Quote from the [sitemaps.org
FAQ](http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_sitemap_size):

> Sitemaps should be no larger than 50MB (52,428,800 bytes) and can contain a
>   maximum of 50,000 URLs. These limits help to ensure that your web server does
>   not get bogged down serving very large files. This means that if your site
>   contains more than 50,000 URLs or your Sitemap is bigger than 50MB, you must
>   create multiple Sitemap files and use
>   a [Sitemap index file](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#index). You
>   should use a Sitemap index file even if you have a small site but plan on
>   growing beyond 50,000 URLs or a file size of 50MB. A Sitemap index file can
>   include up to 50,000 Sitemaps and must not exceed 50MB (52,428,800 bytes). You
>   can also use gzip to compress your Sitemaps.

The above answer can be considered authoritative. According to
sitemaps.org's [terms of service](http://www.sitemaps.org/terms.html), as of May
2017, sitemaps.org is sponsored by: Google, Inc., Yahoo, Inc., and Microsoft
Corporation

Answer (score 3):

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/nd5RDhMMfhk

Q:

> I've read the FAQs and searched the help center.
>
> This URL indicates the max sitemap file size is 50 MB, uncompressed:
>   http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183668#1
>
> This URL indicates the max sitemap file size is 10 MB, uncompressed:
>   http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_sitemap_size

A:

> Both are correct!  How?
>
> On sitemaps.org the 10MB figure is the standard figure in the standard
>   protocol.
>
> Google later decided to INCREASE the upper limit to 50MB for people
>   submitting to Google, so that's why it says 50MB on the google help
>   notes.
>
> If you want your XML Sitemaps to be compatible not only with google
>   but others that accept XML Sitemaps, you might still want to limit
>   each to a maximum filesize of 10MB (i.e. regardless of compressed or
>   uncompressed should never exceed 10MB).

Comment: ya, it's somehow confusing, please also see a similar answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887358/limitation-for-google-sitemap-xml-file-size/34972582#answer-34972582