# If the capacity was 50,000 sitemap what to do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

If capacity of more than 50,000 sitemap What should we do?
Should a new xml sitemap file to be created?
How do I do?
Thank.

Comment: Explain your problem, post the code which you have tried to solve your problem.

Comment: I want to know that, after the number was more than 50,000 in the sitemap. What will I do?

Comment: Then you need to use sitemap index, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887358/limitation-for-google-sitemap-xml-file-size