# If robots.txt points to a sitemap in a sub-folder, can the sitemap specify URLs in the root?

Tags: html, sitemap, robots.txt

Suppose I have a robots.txt file in my root, `http://domain.com/robots.txt`, that specifies a sitemap in a sub-folder that has a single declaration that points to a sitemap index:

**robots.txt**

```
Sitemap: http://domain.com/sub/sitemap_index.xml
```

Suppose also that the sitemap index points to a `sitemap.xml` that same the sub-directory:

**sitemap_index.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
       <loc>http://domain.com/sub/sitemap-1.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
 </sitemapindex>
```

In the sitemap specification, it clearly states that the sitemap can only specifies URLs in the current folder or sub-folders.  However, does this change in the scenario I described above? The reason I ask is that I know that a robots.txt file can point to sitemap hosted on a completely different domain.  If this is possible, then it stands to reason that a sitemap in a subfolder, but pointed to from robots.txt in the root, can specify URLs in the root and all sub-folders from there.

Anyone know for certain?

Comment: I tested a bit and it seems that Googlebot does not accept Sitemap: lines in robots.txt that are in a subdirectory. The 'blocked URLs' section has a robots.txt tester that also lists the Sitemap line if it can parse it.

Answer (score 0):

**Prelude:**
It seems important to clarify that we're talking about a **protocol** here. That is: of course *could* there be anything in a sitemap, pointing to anywhere else and of course *could* there be software of any kind that interprets the sitemap just like one wants. And of course, there *could* be multiple reasons why - for instance in regards to search engine crawlers - a sitemap *seems* to work or actually works (including that such crawlers *may* accept non-formal formats of sitemaps, because they don't want their service to be hindered by those). A protocol is an agreement between independent entities that allow us to have reliable interactions.

The question points to what (indeed) at first glance appears to be a contradiction within the logic of two sections of the sitemap protocol. If we're super precise about it however, I think we can understand, why the logic is still sound.

**1. The "directory or sub-directory"-rule**

Let's take a fairly well-known search engine: Google. In their developer guidelines they [state](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/build-sitemap#general-guidelines) the following:

> The best practices for sitemaps are defined by the sitemaps protocol.
> The **most overlooked best practices** are related to the size limits,
> **sitemap location**, and the URLs included in the sitemaps.

(Emphasis by me). They link to the [sitemap protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location) that every major search engine has adopted.

The relevant part:

> The location of a Sitemap file determines the set of URLs that can be
> included in that Sitemap. A Sitemap file located at
> http://example.com/catalog/sitemap.xml can include any URLs starting
> with http://example.com/catalog/ but can not include URLs starting
> with http://example.com/images/.
>
> If you have the permission to change
> http://example.org/path/sitemap.xml, it is assumed that you also have
> permission to provide information for URLs with the prefix
> http://example.org/path/.

Why is that? Just as the protocol implicitly states, the fact that you have control over *http://example.org/path_a* does not guarantee you having control about *http://example.org/path_b*. For individual users, it used to be pretty typical that you shared a domain and had your web pages in a specific sub-directory. Similarly, in larger businesses, you may have different people or teams responsible for certain sections of a site. **The gist is**: according to this section of the sitemap protocol, one should be strict about the "same directory or its sub-directories" rule.

*Note that in the examples given below the cited paragraphs, you can see that this differentiation extends to http and https versions of the same address, for similar reason: you could deliver entirely different content on port 80 vs. port 443.*

**2. The external sitemap rule**

Right below that however, they give an example of how to handle cross submits, that is submitting URLs for your `host1` through a sitemap hosted on `host2`. Their solution is that by pointing to the external sitemap for your `host1` on `host2` in your robots.txt, "you have implicitly proven that you own host1" and that you trust the sitemap on `host2` to contain URLs for your `host1`.

Note that this doesn't allow a wild mix:

> When a particular host's robots.txt, say http://www.host1.com/robots.txt, points to a Sitemap or a Sitemap index on another host; it is expected that for each of the target Sitemaps, such as http://www.sitemaphost.com/sitemap-host1.xml, all the URLs belong to the host pointing to it. This is because, as noted earlier, a Sitemap is expected to have URLs from a single host only.

This may appear to not be the same strict precision-level as in the other rule and thereby contradict it. Coming back to the question:

> The reason I ask is that I know that a robots.txt file can point to sitemap hosted on a completely different domain. If this is possible, then it stands to reason that a sitemap in a subfolder, but pointed to from robots.txt in the root, can specify URLs in the root and all sub-folders from there.

Within that scenario, indeed it does sound reasonable, but let me make the argument for why you shouldn't do it, by comparing the two cases:

**In case A**, we point to an externally hosted sitemap from our robots.txt and thereby advice search engines to use that sitemap as a base to index our host, that is: the root and every possible sub-directory. Here it seems reasonable to assume that we want to convey information about the entirety of our site, or, that we would have multiple external sitemaps containing URLs of different parts of our site. Are there good reasons for this practice? Sure - for instance if the process that generates your Sitemaps should not be able to write to your site.

**In case B**, we would point to a sub-directory and expect the same behavior. For this, we don't find particular precedence in the sitemaps protocol. We can only *argue* that it could be the same as case A. Then however, it would be prone to *ambiguous interpretation*: "is this sitemap in sub-directory X to be handled in the same way an external sitemap would - or - is it to be handled as the sitemap specific to that sub-directory tree?"

**Since case B could only ever be ambiguous**, I'd argue that this isn't the way to go. The correct way of doing it would be to include multiple Sitemaps or alternatively Sitemap indices in the robots.txt as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594179/multiple-sitemap-entries-in-robots-txt) – none, one or several per sub-directory, depending on your specific use case.

**Conclusion**

1. sitemaps on the same host: follow the first rule.
2. externally hosted sitemaps: follow the second rule-set

*Every other, possibly undocumented, behavior by search engines should be considered unreliable and not be taken for granted.*

Answer (score 0):

In the case you outlined, when a sitemap index in a subdirectory is referred to by the robots.txt file in a domain's root directory, and that sitemap index in turn leads to specific sitemap files inside that subfolder, the sitemap definition holds true.

A sitemap file can only include URLs that are contained in the current folder or any of its subfolders, per the specifications of the sitemap protocol. As a result, the individual sitemap files that the sitemap index references must follow the same guidelines, even though the robots.txt file may be located in the root directory and point to a sitemap index in a subfolder. Only URLs from the same subdirectory or any of its subdirectories may be included.

The range of URLs that can be included in the sitemap files is unaffected by the location of the robots.txt file or the layout of the sitemap index. The requirement that a sitemap file contain only URLs contained in its own folder or subfolders must still be followed by every sitemap file.

Answer (score -1):

yes it will change in the scenario you mentioned above. In the above scenario your Robot.txt can point to the same domain url's from any directory either sub or main.

Answer (score -1):

Im pretty sure that the *robots.txt* file points to a sitemap located in the sub-folder, the sitemap can still specify URLs that are in the root directory of the site.
Thats most likely because the location of the sitemap does not restrict the links that can be included in the sitemap itself, so as long as the sitemap is accessible to search engine crawlers and contains the relevant URLs for indexing, it can include URLs from any part of the website.

Comment: The [Sitemap Protocol document](https://sitemaps.org/protocol.html) states, "The location of a Sitemap file determines the set of URLs that can be included in that Sitemap. A Sitemap file located at http://example.com/catalog/sitemap.xml can include any URLs starting with http://example.com/catalog/ but can not include URLs starting with http://example.com/images/."